# SQL Server 2012 deadlock transaction issue

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

We are currently experiencing deadlocks on our database but the statements are referencing completely different tables.

e.g. One of the statements is delete from Table A where username = P0 and
the other statement is delete from table B where username = P1

There is a page lock on Table A when the deadlock occurs but I'm not sure why this would affect the delete against Table B ?

There are no FK constraints between the tables.

All I can think of is that the deadlocking statements are contained within transactions - is there any way I can get more information regarding this.

I have the XACT's in the deadlock XML report but I am not sure which DMV these XACT's are contained in ?

Comment: If the executors of each DELETE are themselves waiting for locks on the other table, then this might cause a deadlock.

Comment: How can I confirm this based on the deadlock report XML and diagram ?